# web security issue?

Tags: asp.net, security, web

My team have been asked to 'enhance' a web app to permit the following. Is this considered a security risk in a web app? I'm not sure about this.

"Be able to access directories, for exporting and importing [data into the database] , outside of the virtual directory"

In other words the requester wishes to be able to navigate to a data file anywhere outside the application's IIS virtual directory, presumably when importing (or exporting) data.

I think this means on the web server, but it may mean local files on the client machine (to be clarified). But either way the question stands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question does not stand 'either way'. They are different questions. If it is about being able to select a file from the local computer to send to the remote server then that is pretty routine. e.g. one does it all the time while attaching a file to an email. The user is the one who initiates the file choice AND it is their file to send to the web app. No security hole here.

IF you have a need to allow clients to be able to browse the server computer for all sorts of files, then that itself is NOT a security hole. That is what you wanted, you got it. It is a security hole ONLY when you did not mean that the client should be able to grab hold of files off any whichever directory on the server. This whole scenario is classified as security issue because more often than not you do NOT want clients to have access to all inclusive files on the server. Typically the client needs to be able to access only certain files. Restricting you to virtual directory is one way of doing it. e.g. would you want your clients to be able to grab hold of the actual DB files with records of all users of your web site and then load that DB file in their own DB?

If you need to go beyond that, you need to implement mechanisms in place that allow access to only certain files. Remember your web server is running in the context of some user on the server OS. When the client request comes to the server, it that that web server user under which the command executes. So you cannot achieve security by simply putting in permissions for that web server user.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about going outside the boundaries of the web application, that means a risk. Once you allow a particular user to go beyond your web application, then there is no more control in what that user could do with the webserver.

Have a look at path traversal attacks:

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Path_Traversal

Also, here is a list of things to consider in order to avoid this:

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/File_System#Path_traversal

Any questions, just let me know.

Regards,
Fabio
@fcerullo

Comment: Thanks. It's not an area I am knowledgable in, but I smelled a bad smell as soon as I saw the requirement. Resist, or get the client to sign a discaimer, seems to be the sensible approach.